# How to change the VALUE of Textbox?

Tags: javascript

after i check the checkbox the text_box value = 1 
but after i unchecked the checkbox the text_box value not return to 0
please help me THANK_YOU.. java_script problem.

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="0">
```

`<input type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction()">`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myText").value = "1";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {

    var val = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("myText").value = val == "0" ? "1" : "0";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the value to "1". If you want to toggle the value on checking and unchecking the checkbox, then do it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  if(document.getElementById('myText').checked) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "1";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "0";
  }
}
```

OR

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('myText').value = document.getElementById('myText').checked? "1": "0";
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('myText').checked == true` can be reduced to `document.getElementById('myText').checked` .

Comment: Yeah we can do that. I will edit that in the answer.